# Use a model (resource) attribute (accessor) with metrics in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a MySQL table called `purchases` and a model called `Purchase` in Laravel that is related to it. My table has two columns, `quantity` and `unit_cost`. The total cost of a purchase is not a column in my table. Instead, it is defined by an accessor in Laravel that multiplies `unit_cost` by `quantity` and returns it as `total_cost`.

Now I am trying to define a trend metric in Laravel nova that is supposed to output the value of my daily sales in the selected range. When I try to use `return $this->sumByDays($request, Purchase::class, 'total_cost')` it gives me an error that says `total_cost` is not a column.

Fair enough! So, I tried to use `Purchase::selectRaw(DB::RAW('unit_cost * quantity AS total_cost'))` in the second argument, but it didn't work. I saw multiple posts, none of them could solve the problem of accessing a model accessor in Laravel Nova metrics. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use the built-in `sumByDays` helper function.

But good news! You can still implement it yourself within the `calculate` function. Just make sure your function returns a `Laravel\Nova\Metrics\TrendResult`.

Something like this:

```php
$purchases = DB::table('purchases')
    ->select(DB::raw('quantity * unit_cost as total_cost'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) DESC'))
    ->get();

return new TrendResult()
    ->trend($purchases);
```

I don't have time to test this at the moment but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, but can you expand your answer? I have no idea how I can implement it within the ``calculate`` function.

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense. But it seems to me that I should handle range selection on my own. Is there any way that I can know what date range the user has selected in the ``calculate`` function? Otherwise I don't see how I can modify my query to account for that.

Comment: I ended up rewriting almost everything in ``Trend`` class in Laravel Nova, but it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't mind, perhaps you could share some of the code you wrote as an answer to your own question to help people in the future! :)

Answer (score 1):

While trying to fix this problem, I checked through the sum by day or hours code and I realised that the column is an instance of Query Expression.

So that means you can still use the built in nova sum by days.

Make sure you import `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;`

Just do this

```
$xpression = new Expression('quantity * unit_cost');
return $this->sumByDays($request, Purchase::class, $xpression);
```

It worked for me easily, I hope it does for others too.

The expression could be used in various ways in my case it was to perform a different calculation.